# How to wait for the image to load before the cycle "for" goes on in onDataChange + Glide?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

I know that the onDataChange download is asynchronous, but the body has UI Thread. And loading images using Glide is also asynchronous. onDataChange is being executed, it comes to the body of the UI Thread, but there the image is loaded in the new thread and, therefore, the image does not have time to load, how the code is executed further.

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              ...
              if(word.contains("https")){
                  Glide.with(Activity.this)
                  .load(url)
                  .into(imageView);
              }else{
                  Log.d(TAG, "Another");
              }
         }
    }
}
```

This is Firebase database.

**How to wait for the image to load before the cycle "for" goes on?**

Comment: Do you mean you need to load image first and then call onDataChange??

Comment: You can store the value of dataSnapshot in a list, and perform image loading in a different method using the list of data which you call after the onDataChange task is completed.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt No, at first, in onDataChange need to load image, then imageSend(imageView);

Comment: Which version of Glide do you use?

Comment: @DougStevenson At first, in onDataChange need to load image, then imageSend(imageView);

Comment: @RutvikBhatt 4.8.0

Comment: @InnaAhtina put the Glide code in if condition and do whatever you want in else part

Comment: @RutvikBhatt Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question. I think now the question is asked correctly.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question. I think now the question is asked correctly.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question. I think now the question is asked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Glide-v4`, you can set a listener for loading the image like this:

```
Glide.with(Activity.this)
        .load(url)
        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                imageSend(imageView);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question. I think now the question is asked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Glide` logic in a method passing `dataSnapshot` as param. Something like this :

```
Glide.with(Activity.this)
 .load(url)
 .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
     @Override
     public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
         imageSend(imageView);
         return false;
     }
 })
 .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I updated the code, I need to prevent the execution situation from "else" while loading the image in "if"

Comment: put this logic in a private method in your class, and call it when `if condition` is true

Comment: Due to the fact that Glide is asynchronous, the code is executed further, without waiting for the download.

Comment: If you put the code like this, it won't execute further (imageSend won't get called unless `onResourceReady` has been triggered). Also, there is nothing to be executed further.. I don't see your point here

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help, I will mark your question as correct and will re-create the question with great details. Tell me, is it possible in this case to create a new question or is it better to edit this one?

Comment: Better edit this one with all the details related to the issue.

Comment: Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question. I think now the question is asked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Declare a global variable:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

add urls to list:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot childDS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       list.add(childDS.getValue(String.class));
   }
   setImages(list); // this function will be called only after all the URLs are added to the list 
 }
}
```

Create a new method:

```
void setImages(ArrayList<String> urlList){
  for(int i = 0; i<urlList.size; i++){
   if(urlList.get(i).contains("https")){
         Glide.with(Activity.this)
         .load(url)
         .into(imageView);
         imageSend(imageView);
    }else{
         Log.d(TAG, "Another");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the question and code now. I would be grateful for the help in the question.